# Why does calling methods on a protobuf Message throw a pure virtual method called error?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I'm trying to use the Google Protobuf library and I want to store a bunch of different message types together in a container and get their names as I pull them out of the container. I think I can use the interface type `google::protobuf::Message` to do this. Here is what I have so far.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "addressbook.pb.h"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
  vector<shared_ptr<google::protobuf::Message>> vec;
  
  {
    tutorial::AddressBook address_book;
    vec.push_back(shared_ptr<google::protobuf::Message>(&address_book));
  }

  cout << "Typename is " << vec.back()->GetTypeName() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Calling `GetTypeName` throws the following error:

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Note this is me playing around with the tutorial found here:
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

Comment: You can not instantiate a `protobuf::Message` object, because it is an abstract interface class with no implementation. You have to derive your own implementation adhering tot hat interface.

Comment: I'm not instantiating an `Message` object though. I have a pointer to it.

Comment: Apart from anything else you pass ownership of the locally scoped object `address_book` to a shared pointer and then access that object *after* it has gone out of scope.  You have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @G.M. shouldn't the shared pointer keep the object alive?

Comment: `address_book` is on the stack it will be deleted when it goes out of scope, nothing can prevent that. Just create your book with `std::make_shared`

Comment: @al3c Do you want to write an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address_book` is on the stack it will be deleted when it goes out of scope, no smart pointer can prevent that.

Just create your book with `std::make_shared`, that will be on the heap and its lifetime will be managed from the `std::shared_ptr`.

```cpp
{
    auto address_book = shared_ptr<google::protobuf::Message>(new tutorial::AddressBook);
    vec.push_back(address_book);
}
```